# Phalcon micro app routes regex pattern (all except words)

Tags: php, regex, path, routes, phalcon

Im lost with the phalcon regex routes pattern.

I want to get the id (f.e.)

`url/foo/bar/baz/some123id`

So `id` can be anything **but** `count` and `find`.

**Paths:**

`/count` *return entity count*

`/find` *find entity by query (?foo=123&...)*

`/{id}` *usually search by id (does not work)*

**Tried**

`/{id:[^count|find]*}` Does not work with `/123c` (c is in "count")

Tried to fix this using online regex:

`/{id:^(?!^count$|^find$).+}`

Worked like expected. See https://regex101.com/r/jC8nB0/230

[image]

But if i am using this regex in a phalcon route it does not work at all.

**What am i doing wrong?**

---

**Solution:**

*EDIT*

Solution 1: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49123320/3411766 (mickmackusa)

Solution 2: (not perfect i think)

*/EDIT*

`\/*((?!count$|find$)[^\/\r\n\t]+)\/*`

**Why:**

I checked what phalcon used as compiled pattern:

```
foreach ($app->getRouter()->getRoutes() as $route) {
    file_put_contents('tmp/_test.log', var_export($route->getCompiledPattern(), true) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

and

`/{id:^(?!^count$|^find$).+}`

became to

`#^/^(?!^count$|^find$).+$#u`

And i think as **Leyff da** mentioned the `^` is the problem.

---

Example of a `/foo/bar/` -path:

`/foo/bar/{id:\/*((?!count$|find$)[^\/\r\n\t]+)\/*}`

becomes to

`#^\/foo\/bar\/\/*((?!count$|find$)[^\/\r\n\t]+)\/*$#u`

Pattern break down:

```
#                                       delimiter
    ^                                   start of string
        \/foo\/bar\/                    path
        \/*                             possible multiple slashes before id like "foo/bar///id123"
            (                           capture id
                (
                    ?!                  negative lookahead
                    count               string
                        $               end of string (to not match f.e. counts, count1, ...)
                    |                   or
                    find                string
                        $               end of string (to not match f.e. finds, find1, ...)
                )
                [^\/\r\n\t]+            do not capture slashes, tab or new line after id
            )
        \/*                             possible multiple slashes after id like "foo/bar/id123///"
    $                                   end of string
#                                       delimiter
u                                       unicode
```

Comment: "does not work at all" is very vague. What are you expecting and what are the actual results? (no results, errors, computer freezing or.....)

Comment: @AndréKool See link i posted (https://regex101.com/r/jC8nB0/230) There is examples that match as i expected. (count and find does not match)

Comment: You said when you used that regex in phalcon route is does not work at all. My question is if you can specify that because does not work can be a lot of different things.

Comment: There is no error. It just does not match the route. F.e. `url/sku` should match because `sku` is not `count` and not `find`.

Comment: The two  `^`before count and find are useless given that you already write it before the negative lookahead.

Comment: `^` is used to check the begin of the string, did you but something before ? `/{id:` could block the regex, it would be impossible.

Comment: @Leyffda I am using this to define `^` start of line and `$` end of line. Phalcon sure gets a string after the last slash `/`. So in example `url/sku` i would get `sku` as string (afik).

Comment: Try the regex with the full string :)

Comment: @Leyffda What you mean with something before? This is the path im currerntly using `/foo/bar/{id:^(?!^count$|^find$).+}` (where foo and bar are paths to the service controller)

Comment: Can you provide juste a full string that would match ? Not the regex, I strugle to get the id part :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165429/discussion-between-cottton-and-leyff-da).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disqualify specific substrings, `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` is a handy technique.  After disqualifying `count` and `find` you can use `[^/\r\n\t]+` to match any number of valid characters.

Raw Pattern: `/foo/bar/+(?:(?:find|count)/*$(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|([^/\r\n\t]+))/*`

Phalcon-wrapped Pattern: `#^/foo/bar/+(?:(?:find|count)/*$(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|([^/\r\n\t]+))/*$#u`

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jC8nB0/257)

Pattern Breakdown:

```
#                                    // pattern starting delimiter
^                                    // match start of the string
/foo/bar                             // literally match /foo/bar
/+                                   // match (as much as possible) one or more forward slashes
(?:                                  // start a non-capturing group (to maintain pattern logic/intent)
    (?:find|count)/*$(*SKIP)(*FAIL)  // match the words: find or count followed immediately by zero or more forward slashes then the end of the string ...if a match force then entire string to fail
    |                                // or
    ([^/\r\n\t]+)                    // capture one or more (as much as possible) characters that are not: forward slash, line return, newline, tab
)                                    // end non-capturing group
/*                                   // match zero or more forward slashes
$                                    // match the end of the string
#                                    // pattern ending delimiter
u                                    // pattern modifier: allow unicode characters
```

Comment: This does not match the id-group. I added grouping around `(.*)` and changed to `+` to not match "nothing" after slash `(.+)`. See https://regex101.com/r/PItBtl/3 Will try this. But atm i got this in production: https://regex101.com/r/PItBtl/2

Comment: I would like to update my answer with a more refined pattern.  Can you provide some more realistic samples so that I can be sure that `\*` is necessary?  Are there spaces in the `id` component?  Is this task about validation or extraction?

Comment: Is `/foo/bar//count//` a _possible_ input string which needs to be disqualified?  Your "in production" pattern will not disqualify it.  I am happy to help, but to provide the best / most accurate pattern I need to be better informed of the variability of your strings.  I am leaning toward this at the moment: https://regex101.com/r/PItBtl/4

Comment: @cottton Is there any chance that you have a strict range of characters that a valid `id` can contain?  Will it be only numbers and letters? Can there be spaces? hyphens? underscores? etc?

Comment: Its about extraction. Phalcon expects a pattern to match the path and to extract the id.
Double slashes or unnecessary slashes should work too.
`foo/bar/{id}/` or `foo/bar//{id}//` must work like `foo/bar/{id}`.
But `foo//bar/{id}` must not (invalid|not matching the path imo. But i think phalcon takes care of that).
And yes you are right: /foo/bar//count// does not work on my current pattern :/
An id can be anything BUT slashes. As long its unicode.
Note: phalcon ads prepends `#^` and appends `$#u` to the given pattern.

Comment: @cottton let's move this page toward a resolution.  I've added a new pattern that I think will behave as desired.  If this does it, please award the green tick.  If it doesn't please show me some sample strings that it fails to process properly.

Comment: you forgot the id capturing again ;) So at the end of the pattern it should be `...([^/]+)`. I think thats it. This is what i currently use: https://regex101.com/r/jC8nB0/237 And this the same test with your pattern: https://regex101.com/r/jC8nB0/255 (added the capturing ...) Same result except for the trailing slashes.  Im gonna mark this as accepted answer. (even if i still dont understand the SKIP FAIL part :D ) Thanks man!

Comment: Stop. I forgot the `^` and `$` phalcon adds to the string (^...$). So here is the test with your pattern and it does not work: https://regex101.com/r/jC8nB0/256 I have no idea why.

Comment: So are we saying this is the pattern that you send: `/foo/bar/+(?:(?:find|count)/*$(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|([^/\r\n\t]+))/*` and that pattern gets wrapped with `#^` and `$#u` to become `#^/foo/bar/+(?:(?:find|count)/*$(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|([^/\r\n\t]+))/*#u` ? this should work: https://regex101.com/r/jC8nB0/257  (because the pattern delimiter is `#`, you don't need to escape the forward slashes) Think of `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` as  the bouncer of a night club -- you might be cashed-up and ready to dance, but if you're not wearing the right shoes, you don't get in the door.

Comment: Yep. That works. Pls update your answer. I accepted it - ppl who search for phalcon route pattern would try the "old" pattern. Thanks for the help! (is is actually possible to change an accepted answer? If not let me know)

Comment: Yes, the green tick can ALWAYS be moved, and I am a strong advocate for moving the green tick when something better is posted.  Too often on this site, askers award the green tick too soon and when a superior method comes along the best answer is not recognized.  This leads volunteers to believe it is not worth it to visit accepted pages.  So pages can be left with suboptimal answers that future researchers will assume are best solved with the accepted answer.  Could my stance come back to bite me?  Only in regard to rep points.  I always post my best answer.  If someone else posts an answer

Comment: better than mine and I lose the green tick, then I am not sad about losing 15 points, I am happy that I have been shown a superior approach.  On StackOverflow (and in life), I am never a loser if I am a learner.  Finally, the green tick is very powerful (and sticky). Transient researchers (who don't know what the green tick really means on StackOverflow) will assume the green tick means "this is the best way" (versus what can be "meh, this worked for me").  When the accepted answer is suboptimal, it is very likely that inferior code will be ignorantly copy/pasted into future projects.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here was the `^` which is the starting of the string, and not the starting of your matching regex. A `somthing^something` is then impossible to match.
Solution : `(?<=.*\/)[^/]+(?<!find|count)$`

Explanation
`(?<=.*\/)` Positive lookbehind to get a slash
`[^/]+` one or more characters which are not the slash
`(?<!find|count)` negative lookbehind to be sure it's not 'count' or 'find'
`$` end of the regex

If you want to match a specific `foo/bar` path before you need to replace the regex a bit :
`(?<=foo\/bar\/baz\/)[^/]+(?<!find|count)$`

Comment: variable width lookbehinds are not allowed.